# htaccess valid expression is not working

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite some URLs using a regular rule in htaccess, in order to rewrite all the URLs of that kind.
Actual URL:

```
http://www.example.com/pippo-e-pluto?shopid=1000&shopname=Apicella&citta=Milano
```

Desired URL:

```
http://www.example.com/Apicella-Milano-1000
```

I have added this rule to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/%2-%3-%1? /pippo-e-pluto?shopid=$1&shopname=$2&citta=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^shopid=(.*)&shopname=(.*)&citta=(.*)
RewriteRule ^pippo-e-pluto$ /%2-%3-%1? [R=301]
```

BUT it doesn't seem to work. My non SEF url is still the same.
I'm using Joomla 3.6.4, mod_rewrite is on. 
Also asked for support to the hosting service but they couldn't fix this issue.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make your SEF URLs work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)$ pippo-e-pluto?shopid=$2&shopname=$3&citta=$1
```